# jQuery script tag execution order when using $.append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Usually when I have something the likes of below on an HTML page it works just fine.
The local script block is only executed after the external script block is finished loading.

```
<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">         
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
        ['2004',  1000,      400],
        ['2005',  1170,      460],
        ['2006',  660,       1120],
        ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);
        
        var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };
        
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
        
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }         
</script>
```

However if I take the code above and append it to a DIV container like this:

`$("#some_element").append($.parseHTML([code from above here], document, true));`

It gives me the message "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined".
I think the problem is that when appending this piece of code like this, either the order of the script tags isn't respected, or it just loads all script tags in parallel?!

Now I know there are workarounds to this (primarily using $.getScript and a callback), but I'd like to know why it is like this exyactly, and if there is a way to get it to work like expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you append an HTML string to a DOM node, the default browser behavior blocks the script execution (as a security step to prevent XSS attack). What jQuery does (according to my knowledge) is re-evaluate those scripts. In the cases where there is a script URL, jQuery sends an AJAX request. As you know AJAX is asynchronous, which means that the scripts can resolve in any order (unlike what happens when you use HTML directly). As a result, embedded JavaScript gets executed before the dependency script. You can learn more about it by inspecting the network tab.

```js
$('#someContainer').append(`
<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"><\/div>

<script type="text\/javascript" src="https:\/\/www.gstatic.com\/charts\/loader.js"><\/script>
<script type="text\/javascript">         
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
        ['2004',  1000,      400],
        ['2005',  1170,      460],
        ['2006',  660,       1120],
        ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);
        
        var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };
        
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
        
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }         
<\/script>
`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="someContainer"></div>
```

In the screenshot below you can see that the request initiator for `loader.js` script is jQuery. On the right panel you can see `ajax` in the call stack.

[image]